# Prefix Multisite Directory Structure

Tags: multisite

At the moment I have a wordpress Multisite with multiple sites.

- Shop home (root install)
- London (subsite)
- New York (subsite)

To view these sites you navigate to:

- www.example.com
- www.example.com/london
- www.example.com/new-york

I'm trying to work out how to add a prefix to the sub sites, so instead it would look like this:

- www.example.com
- www.example.com/**stores**/london
- www.example.com/**stores**/new-york

How can I do this? Most of the multisite vars don't seem to include it:

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false); // Set to true if using subdirectories
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', env('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE'));
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', "/");
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

And the admin network settings don't seem to either. Am I missing something?