# How to approach prefixing the path of a multisite sub-directory install?

Tags: multisite, directory

Six years ago, someone asked my question, but didn't receive any answers on wpse:
[Prefix Multisite Directory Structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275423/prefix-multisite-directory-structure)

The question was: (how) is it possible to add a prefix the url/path of WP multisite sub-directory installs like this -

example.com/ (main site 1)
example.com/PREFIX/site2
example.com/PREFIX/site3

The question was also asked on reddit, where someone replied by pointing to an even older thread on wpse -

[Multisite in subfolder - How to make new sites to be in same level subfolders as the main site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119493/multisite-in-subfolder-how-to-make-new-sites-to-be-in-same-level-subfolders-as)

which contains a complicated concept for a solution involving manual database manipulation for the network installs.

Even though I couldn't find any straight forward method or documentation, maybe there is? Is this still how you would approach this problem? My initial reaction would have been to look at rewrite rules instead of database manipulation if there is still no documented and standard way to achieve such a setup.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: One simpler workaround I'm just thinking of seems to be: 

Have a regular install at example.com and install a multisite-network in the subdirectory example.com/PREFIX/, which will then give sub-installs at example.com/PREFIX/SITE1 and example.com/PREFIX/site2